# SiegelTheta fails to evaluate when given proper arguments

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions

SiegelTheta often returns error messages when I give it arguments that should be of the correct form. For instance, I have a numerical matrix like

```
M = N[{{1 + π/2, -1, 1 - π/2}, {-1, 1 + π/2, -1}, {1 - π/2, -1, 1 + π/2}}];
```

and I want to evaluate `SiegelTheta[Ω[0.01], s]`, where

```
Ω[r_] := I*Inverse[M]/r

s = {0, 0, 0};
```

but I get the following error message:

```
SiegelTheta::invmat:
"{{0. + 56.831I,0. + 31.831I,0. + 25.I},{0. + 31.831I,0. + 63.662I,0. +31.831I},
{0. + 25.I,0. + 31.831I,0. + 56.831I}} must be a symmetric matrix with a positive definite 
imaginary part."
```

However, `Ω[0.01]` does satisfy those conditions, even according to Mathematica:

```
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[Im[Ω[0.01]]]
(* True *)

SymmetricMatrixQ[Ω[0.01]]
(* True *)
```

I would appreciate any help resolving this issue. I am using Mathematica version 9.0.1.

Comment: While Im[Ω[0.01]] is positive definite, Ω[0.01] is not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but according to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SiegelTheta.html), it is the imaginary part of the matrix that has to be positive definite. For instance, the first example in the documentation is the matrix {{I, -1/2}, {-1/2, I}}, which is not positive definite, but whose imaginary part is.

Comment: Note that `Ω[0.01][[2, 1]] === Ω[0.01][[1, 2]]` returns `False`. Also, examine this: `Rationalize[#, 0] &@Ω[0.01]`

Comment: If you remove the N from the definition of M, you have `SymmetricMatrixQ@Ω[0.01]` (-> `True`)

Comment: @Sjoerd: You're right, I see. It seems from the source code that SiegelTheta determines whether the input matrix is symmetric by subtracting the transpose and finding whether the result is the zero matrix. And while `Ω[0.01] == Transpose[Ω[0.01]]` evaluates as `True`, apparently the difference between `Ω[0.01]` and its transpose is not zero (for instance `MatrixRank[Ω[0.01] - Transpose[Ω[0.01]]]` evaluates to `2`). Do you have any suggestions for how to get around this and get an answer from SiegelTheta?

Comment: @Jacob: Indeed, if I remove N from the definition of M then SiegelTheta doesn't encounter any problems. However, I need to be able to get a result for numerical matrices; the M matrix I gave above was just a simple example of the kind of matrix I'm using.

Comment: How about: `SiegelTheta[(Ω[0.01] + Transpose[Ω[0.01]])/2,s]`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Sjoerd's suggestion of taking the symmetric part of your matrix `(mat + Transpose[mat])/2`, here is another way:

```
makesym[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
        UpperTriangularize[mat] + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]]

SiegelTheta[Ω[0.01] // makesym, s]
   1. + 0.*I
```